# lift in this monad to reach the reader's data

Tags: haskell

I have this monad:

```hs
newtype App a = App { runApp :: ExceptT ServerError (LoggingT (ReaderT AppConfig Handler)) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader AppConfig, MonadError ServerError, MonadIO, MonadLogger) via (ExceptT ServerError (LoggingT (ReaderT AppConfig Handler)))
```

I thought I can reach the AppConfig in Reader with this lifting

```
lift . lift ask
```

but it is not working.
Can you help me how I can reach this function and the AppConfig data ?

thanks in advance!

I tried to reach the AppConfig data with

```
lift . lift ask
```

Comment: Do you want `lift . lift $ ask` instead?

Comment: Or `lift (lift ask)`

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the specific monad transformers, you can see in GHCi that you want the *composition* of `lift . lift` applied to `ask`, rather than `lift` being applied to the result of `lift ask`:

```
> :t lift . lift ask
[type error redacted]

> :t lift . lift $ ask
lift . lift $ ask
  :: (MonadTrans t1, MonadTrans t2, Monad m,
      Monad (t2 (ReaderT a m))) =>
     t1 (t2 (ReaderT a m)) a
```

Substitute `t1 ~ ExceptT ServerError`, `t2 ~ LoggigT`, `a ~ AppConfig`, and `m ~  Handler`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
I had to realize that I can use the "ask" only because the "MonadReader AppConfig" deriving...